# ¿Alguien sabe como solucionar esta parte de mi todolist?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

Yo estoy haciendo un todolist con HTML,CSS y JS. Lo que sucede es que en cada ítem que escribo hasta cierto punto se me corren los botones **EDIT**,  **REMOVE** y todo el texto debajo de la línea. He intentado de todo incluso de un `div`  pero lo que sucede es que como es un elemento de bloque el texto se va para abajo y no se que hacer.

```js
"use strict"
//date function
const dateElement= document.getElementById("date");
const options= {
    weekday:"long",
    month:"short",
    day:"numeric"
                }
const today= new Date();

dateElement.innerHTML= today.toLocaleDateString("en-US",options);


// function add to do

const list= document.getElementById("list");
const input= document.getElementById("input");
const normalButton= document.getElementById("normal");
const finishedTask= document.getElementById("done");
const unfinishedTask= document.getElementById("not-done");


let toDo=[];
let buttonToDo=[];
let editValue=[];
let valueItem= [];
let id;
let idButton;
let editId;



function addToDo(){
    
    //input part
    const itemValue= input.value;
    if(itemValue===""){
        var alerta= alert("Por Favor escribe algo en tu lista");
        return;
    }
    valueItem.push(itemValue);
    console.log(valueItem);

    //creating elements
    const itemNew= document.createElement("li");
    const deleteButton= document.createElement("button");
    const para = document.createElement("scan");
    const editButton= document.createElement("button");
    const checkButton= document.createElement("input");
    
    //creating text
    para.classList.add("text");
    const text= document.createTextNode(itemValue);
    para.appendChild(text);
    

    //check-buttton
    
    checkButton.classList.add("check");
    checkButton.setAttribute("type","checkbox");
    checkButton.value= "not-checked"
    
    //item
    itemNew.classList.add("item");
    itemNew.appendChild(checkButton);           
    itemNew.appendChild(para);
    list.appendChild(itemNew);
    
    

    //edit-button
    editButton.classList.add("edit");
    editButton.value="EDIT";
    let editName= document.createTextNode("EDIT");
    editButton.appendChild(editName);
    itemNew.appendChild(editButton);
    
    //delete-button
    deleteButton.classList.add("delete");
    deleteButton.value="REMOVE";
    let deleteName= document.createTextNode("REMOVE");
    deleteButton.appendChild(deleteName);
    itemNew.appendChild(deleteButton);
    
    //id
    toDo.push(itemNew);
    let id= toDo.indexOf(itemNew);
    console.log(id);

    //id delete-button
    buttonToDo.push(deleteButton);
    let idButton= buttonToDo.indexOf(deleteButton);

    //id edit-button
    editValue.push(editButton);
    let editId= editValue.indexOf(editButton);
    
    //checkbox button
    checkButton.addEventListener("click",()=>{

        if (checkButton.value==="not-checked") {
            checkButton.setAttribute("value","checked");
            checkButton.setAttribute("style","background:#22F700; color: cornsilk ")
            para.setAttribute("style","color:#ACACAC; text-decoration:line-through");
            console.log(checkButton);
        } else {
            checkButton.setAttribute("value","not-checked");
            checkButton.setAttribute("style","background:none; color: none ")
            para.setAttribute("style","color:none; text-decoration:none");
            console.log(checkButton);
        }
        
    });

    //edit button
    editButton.addEventListener("click",()=>{
        if(editId===id){
            let editText= prompt("Inserte aqui el texto a cambiar ...");
            para.innerHTML=editText;
            }
        }
    );


    //delete button
    deleteButton.addEventListener("click",()=>{
            if(idButton===id){
            list.removeChild(itemNew);
            valueItem.splice(id,1);
            console.log(valueItem);
            
            }
        }
    );
    
    //normal button
    normalButton.addEventListener("click",()=>{
        itemNew.setAttribute("style","display:block");
    });

    
    //finished-task button
    finishedTask.addEventListener("click",()=>{
        if (checkButton.value==="checked") {
            itemNew.setAttribute("style","display:block");
            
        } else {
            itemNew.setAttribute("style","display:none");
        }
    });

    //unfinished-task button
    unfinishedTask.addEventListener("click",()=>{
        if (checkButton.value==="not-checked") {
            itemNew.setAttribute("style","display:block");
            
        } else {
            itemNew.setAttribute("style","display:none");
        }
    });

}

document.addEventListener("keyup",(event)=>{ if(event.keyCode===13){addToDo()}});
```

```css
body{
    background-color: #E1E1E1;
}

.container{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 650px;
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.header{
    width: 998px;
    height: 200px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(150deg,#FF014E,#FD0278,#F700F3 );
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: cornsilk;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
}

.title{
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 60px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.ferre{
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;

}

#date{
    font-size: 40px;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;

}

.functionalities{
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 25px 5px 5px 5px;
}

#normal{
    background: none;
    border: none;
    color: cornsilk;
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
    padding: 1px 30px;
}

#done{
    background: none;
    border: none;
    color: cornsilk;
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
    padding: 1px 30px;
}

#not-done{
    background: none;
    border: none;
    color: cornsilk;
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
    padding: 1px 30px;
}

.content{
    width: 998px;
    height: 350px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color: #FFF;
}

#list{
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 20 ;
}

.item{
    width: 900px;
    height: 25px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ACACAC;
}

.text{
    word-break: break-all;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;  
}


.edit{
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    background: none;
    color: #2AE500;
    float: right;
    border-radius: 10px;


}

.delete{
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background: none;
    color: #E10000;
    float: right;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.add-item{
    width: 998px;
    height: 50px;
    border-top: 1px solid #ACACAC;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    background-color: #FFF;
}

#input{
    width: 900px;
    height: 25px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#button{
    background-image: linear-gradient(150deg,#FF014E,#FD0278,#F700F3 );
    color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 10px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <title>To Do List</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <h1 class="title">To Do List App</h1>
            <h2 class="ferre">By Fxrree</h2>
            <!--<div class="clear">
                <i class="refresh" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>-->
            <div id="date">
            </div>
            <div class="functionalities">
                <button id="normal">NORMAL</button>
                <button id="done">DONE</button>
                <button id="not-done">NOT-DONE</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <ul id="list">
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="add-item">
            <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Add Something to Do">
            <button type="submit" id="button" onclick="addToDo()">CLICK ME</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que le estas asignando una altura fija a cada ítem de la lista en tu `CSS`, `height: 25px;`

Justo aquí:

```
.item{
    width: 900px;
    height: 25px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ACACAC;
}
```

Comenté la línea y probé con un párrafo de [lorem ipsum](https://es.lipsum.com/feed/html), ahora la altura se ajusta al texto que introduzcas.

```js
"use strict"
//date function
const dateElement= document.getElementById("date");
const options= {
    weekday:"long",
    month:"short",
    day:"numeric"
                }
const today= new Date();

dateElement.innerHTML= today.toLocaleDateString("en-US",options);


// function add to do

const list= document.getElementById("list");
const input= document.getElementById("input");
const normalButton= document.getElementById("normal");
const finishedTask= document.getElementById("done");
const unfinishedTask= document.getElementById("not-done");


let toDo=[];
let buttonToDo=[];
let editValue=[];
let valueItem= [];
let id;
let idButton;
let editId;



function addToDo(){
    
    //input part
    const itemValue= input.value;
    if(itemValue===""){
        var alerta= alert("Por Favor escribe algo en tu lista");
        return;
    }
    valueItem.push(itemValue);
    console.log(valueItem);

    //creating elements
    const itemNew= document.createElement("li");
    const deleteButton= document.createElement("button");
    const para = document.createElement("scan");
    const editButton= document.createElement("button");
    const checkButton= document.createElement("input");
    
    //creating text
    para.classList.add("text");
    const text= document.createTextNode(itemValue);
    para.appendChild(text);
    

    //check-buttton
    
    checkButton.classList.add("check");
    checkButton.setAttribute("type","checkbox");
    checkButton.value= "not-checked"
    
    //item
    itemNew.classList.add("item");
    itemNew.appendChild(checkButton);           
    itemNew.appendChild(para);
    list.appendChild(itemNew);
    
    

    //edit-button
    editButton.classList.add("edit");
    editButton.value="EDIT";
    let editName= document.createTextNode("EDIT");
    editButton.appendChild(editName);
    itemNew.appendChild(editButton);
    
    //delete-button
    deleteButton.classList.add("delete");
    deleteButton.value="REMOVE";
    let deleteName= document.createTextNode("REMOVE");
    deleteButton.appendChild(deleteName);
    itemNew.appendChild(deleteButton);
    
    //id
    toDo.push(itemNew);
    let id= toDo.indexOf(itemNew);
    console.log(id);

    //id delete-button
    buttonToDo.push(deleteButton);
    let idButton= buttonToDo.indexOf(deleteButton);

    //id edit-button
    editValue.push(editButton);
    let editId= editValue.indexOf(editButton);
    
    //checkbox button
    checkButton.addEventListener("click",()=>{

        if (checkButton.value==="not-checked") {
            checkButton.setAttribute("value","checked");
            checkButton.setAttribute("style","background:#22F700; color: cornsilk ")
            para.setAttribute("style","color:#ACACAC; text-decoration:line-through");
            console.log(checkButton);
        } else {
            checkButton.setAttribute("value","not-checked");
            checkButton.setAttribute("style","background:none; color: none ")
            para.setAttribute("style","color:none; text-decoration:none");
            console.log(checkButton);
        }
        
    });

    //edit button
    editButton.addEventListener("click",()=>{
        if(editId===id){
            let editText= prompt("Inserte aqui el texto a cambiar ...");
            para.innerHTML=editText;
            }
        }
    );


    //delete button
    deleteButton.addEventListener("click",()=>{
            if(idButton===id){
            list.removeChild(itemNew);
            valueItem.splice(id,1);
            console.log(valueItem);
            
            }
        }
    );
    
    //normal button
    normalButton.addEventListener("click",()=>{
        itemNew.setAttribute("style","display:block");
    });

    
    //finished-task button
    finishedTask.addEventListener("click",()=>{
        if (checkButton.value==="checked") {
            itemNew.setAttribute("style","display:block");
            
        } else {
            itemNew.setAttribute("style","display:none");
        }
    });

    //unfinished-task button
    unfinishedTask.addEventListener("click",()=>{
        if (checkButton.value==="not-checked") {
            itemNew.setAttribute("style","display:block");
            
        } else {
            itemNew.setAttribute("style","display:none");
        }
    });

}

document.addEventListener("keyup",(event)=>{ if(event.keyCode===13){addToDo()}});
```

```css
body{
    background-color: #E1E1E1;
}

.container{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 650px;
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.header{
    width: 998px;
    height: 200px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(150deg,#FF014E,#FD0278,#F700F3 );
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: cornsilk;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
}

.title{
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 60px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.ferre{
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;

}

#date{
    font-size: 40px;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;

}

.functionalities{
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 25px 5px 5px 5px;
}

#normal{
    background: none;
    border: none;
    color: cornsilk;
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
    padding: 1px 30px;
}

#done{
    background: none;
    border: none;
    color: cornsilk;
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
    padding: 1px 30px;
}

#not-done{
    background: none;
    border: none;
    color: cornsilk;
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
    padding: 1px 30px;
}

.content{
    width: 998px;
    height: 350px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color: #FFF;
}

#list{
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 20 ;
}

.item{
    width: 900px;
    //height: 25px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ACACAC;
}

.text{
    word-break: break-all;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;  
}


.edit{
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    background: none;
    color: #2AE500;
    float: right;
    border-radius: 10px;


}

.delete{
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background: none;
    color: #E10000;
    float: right;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.add-item{
    width: 998px;
    height: 50px;
    border-top: 1px solid #ACACAC;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    background-color: #FFF;
}

#input{
    width: 900px;
    height: 25px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#button{
    background-image: linear-gradient(150deg,#FF014E,#FD0278,#F700F3 );
    color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 10px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <title>To Do List</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <h1 class="title">To Do List App</h1>
            <h2 class="ferre">By Fxrree</h2>
            <!--<div class="clear">
                <i class="refresh" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>-->
            <div id="date">
            </div>
            <div class="functionalities">
                <button id="normal">NORMAL</button>
                <button id="done">DONE</button>
                <button id="not-done">NOT-DONE</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <ul id="list">
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="add-item">
            <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Add Something to Do">
            <button type="submit" id="button" onclick="addToDo()">CLICK ME</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias portu aclaracion pero el problema que tengo con el texto para ser mas especifico es que yo quiero que mis botones queden como fijos en el lugar y por mas que escriba un caracter o cien caracteres quiero que mi texto como que se rompa y siga abajo sin tener que mover los botones